# Pop Up Chart on a click from within a chart component

Tags: excel, charts, excel-charts, vba

this a possibility question so please dont expect any code although I have tried my best to visualize it.
[example chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpKXm.png) As you can see different regions here, now my question is, can I have a chart pop up when I click on "Asia" Column/Bar and the chart will show the concentration of all Asian countries.

Comment: As in pop-up in a comment box?  It is possible.  It involves saving the chart as a picture in a temp folder and copying that into the comment - I _think_ Ron de Bruin explained it somewhere on his website.  https://www.rondebruin.nl/index.htm

Comment: Yes it is possible. But you'll have to do some serious coding. Good thing is, Jon Peltier discuss about [Chart Events](http://peltiertech.com/chart-events-microsoft-excel/) in his blog.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook The `Chart` object actually has a `CopyPicture` method. You can afterwards do a simple `PasteSpecial` and use a `Shape` object to capture the new picture (`set sh = ws.Shapes(ws.Shapes.Count)`) so you can delete it later. No need to put stuff in folders anywhere.

Comment: @RikSportel Thanks for the clarification.  Knew it was something to do with copying it as a picture, just couldn't remember the detail (been about 10 years since I tried it).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. A very basic implementation to capture these "click on a datapoint in a series" events is the following:

Class module `MouseDownChart` code:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents p_Chart As Chart
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set p_Chart = Nothing
End Sub
Public Sub setChart(ByRef Chart As Chart)
    Set p_Chart = Chart
End Sub
Private Sub p_Chart_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) 'Capture the event
    Dim sertmp As Series
    Dim IDNum As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim B As Long
    p_Chart.GetChartElement x, y, IDNum, a, B
    If IDNum = 3 Then 'Clicked on a point in a chart series
        MsgBox "a is the clicked series: " & a
        MsgBox "B is the clicked datapoint: " & B
        'Write code to pop-up the right stuff here.
    End If
End Sub
```

And in a regular module:

```
Option Explicit
Public mdCht As MouseDownChart

Sub Init()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim co As ChartObject
Dim ch As Chart

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set co = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1)
Set ch = co.Chart
Set mdCht = New MouseDownChart

mdCht.setChart ch

End Sub
```

Keep in mind that a WorksheetChart can be referenced as "Chart", but any chart that is embedded on a worksheet like in your sample picture will always be contained in a `ChartObject`.

Comment: There's probably an easier way, but found that adding to the class `p_Chart_MouseDown` event: `Dim vals as variant` and after the `MsBox` adding `vals = p_chart.SeriesCollection(a).Values` and `MsgBox vals(B)` gave the value of the data point.  Couldn't get it working as a single line of code though...

Comment: If he's after "Asia" he should use something like that for the Xvalues indeed. The answer was more about the event capture though.